# Aggregate character matrix by all columns

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

I'm pretty new to R, so I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but haven't had much luck.

I have a matrix with unknown number of columns and rows at run time. How do I return a count of the number of times a row with matching data occurs?

If I have matrix m:

```
names <- c("John","Bob","John","Sarah","Jill","Sarah","John")
ages <- c("25","36","25","30","55","30","55")
home <- c("USA","Canada","USA","Canada","USA","Canada","Mexico")

m <- data.matrix(cbind(names,ages,home))
```

How do I return the data in this format?

```
+-------+------+--------+-------+
| names | ages |  home  | count |
+-------+------+--------+-------+
| John  |   25 | USA    |     2 |
| Bob   |   36 | Canada |     1 |
| Sarah |   30 | Canada |     2 |
| Jill  |   55 | USA    |     1 |
| John  |   55 | Mexico |     1 |
+-------+------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: I would recommend creating `m` in the following manner `m <- data.frame(names,ages,home)`, as there is no reason having a matrix when you have different column types. Then, you could just do `aggregate(count ~. , transform(m, count = 1), length)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I probably should have provided better sample data. My real data is all in character format and could be millions of rows so I was trying to avoid dataframes for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(m)[,list(count=.N),by=list(names, ages, home)]

#        names ages   home count
#1:  John   25    USA     2
#2:   Bob   36 Canada     1
#3: Sarah   30 Canada     2
#4:  Jill   55    USA     1
#5:  John   55 Mexico     1
```

Comment: instead of hard coding in the column vectors in the "by" section, how would I specify all the columns in the matrix dynamically?

Comment: in that case you can do: `data.table(m)[,list(count=.N),by=eval(colnames(m))]`

Comment: `c` instead of `eval` probably